# Matlab differentiate an inline function

Tags: matlab, newtons-method, differentiation

How can I differentiate my Function `Fun`? When I try to use `diff` it says

> `'diff'` is not supported for class `'inline'`

The code I used is shown below:

```
fprintf('Newton Raphson\n');

Fun=input('\nType a function \n');
xi=input('\nType initial value\n');

def=diff(Fun);

der=inline(def);

dxi=der(xi);
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Also [inline](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html) is depreciated. Better to use anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

Marcin is correct.  Don't use `inline` functions.  Those are no longer used.  If you want to differentiate using the Symbolic Math Toolbox, use [`sym`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.html) to create a function for you, then use this to differentiate it.

As such, do something like this, assuming that `x` is the independent variable:

```
syms x;
fprintf('Newton Raphson\n');

Fun=input('\nType a function \n');
xi=input('\nType initial value\n');

out = sym(Fun);
def = diff(out);
dxi = subs(def, 'x', xi);
```

Note that because the formula is symbolic, if you want to substitute `x` with a particular value, you would need to use [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html).  With `subs`, we are replacing `x` with our initial value stored in `xi`.

---

Let's do a run-through example.  Here's what I get when I run this code, with my inputs and outputs:

```
Newton Raphson

Type a function 
x^2 + x + 3

Type initial value
4
```

`out` would be the function that was input in:

```
out =

x^2 + x + 3
```

`xi` would be the initial value:

```
xi =

4
```

The derivative of the function is stored in `def`:

```
def =

2*x + 1
```

Finally, substituting our initial value into our derivative is stored in `dxi`, and thus gives:

```
dxi =

9
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: `input` should have the `'s'` argument to specify the input to be a string rather than a number.

Comment: @am304 - As long as you define `syms x` at the beginning, then you won't need to have the `'s'` flag, but I do agree that putting the `'s'` is probably more readable and portable.

Answer (score 0):

See this might help you.

```
eq   = input('Write an equation in x','s'); %input a equation
f    = sym(eq);                             %turn the equation into a symbolic one
fin  = inline(char(f));                     %for converting the symbolic function into inline funct
dfin = inline(char(diff(f)));               %for converting the symb diff func into inline diff f
```